# Sharepoint Publish After Test

Tags: sharepoint, testing, synchronization, publish, production

We have test and prod environment for a publishing portal.
What i want to make is keeping synced both environment.

Currently, we make changes on test server and publish content, check the modified pages and if everything is ok we then make same changes on prod server.

Is there any other short way or command to update prod server with last changes made in test server, not doing the same things again and again.

Thanks..

Comment: I thought one of the ideas of SharePoint and publishing portals were revisions - you made a revision, it got approved and only then was it visible. Why are you putting a extra layer on top of this?

Answer (score 0):

On Sharepoint 2010 it's preatty simple: you could run a command in PS to first export the content you need from Test environemnt and then import that content on the Prod Server:

// on Test Environment

**Export-SPWeb *webrooturl* -path "*fullpathfile.cmp*" -includeVersions LastMajor -itemurl Pages -FORCE**

This command create a file .cmp that contains all the latest major version of items in Pages library.
then you have to copy that file .cmp on the target server (Prod) and run

// on Prod Environment

**Import-SPWeb *webrooturl* -path "*fullpathfile.cmp*"**

I used it only for Pages library and works fine, but I think that operating with the parameter **-itemurl** it should be possible to export all the other library contents.

Comment: ste.xin thanks for your response, i will try that. btw is there any sp2007 solution.

Comment: Unfortunately with SP2007 you cannot use PS, so this solution doesn't apply to your case.